# How to plot and view a live animation with Python on a remote Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, raspberry-pi, remote-access

#### Background

I have installed Raspberry Pi OS Lite on a Raspberry Pi 4 (Model B with 1 GB RAM). I am developing Python on the Pi by `ssh`ing from my desktop (e.g. `ssh user@raspberrypi.local`). I am using the Pi to act as a hardware in the loop (HIL) simulator. I am sending data from the HIL to an embedded controller for testing software.

#### Animation does not display when running on remote device

Upon sending data from the HIL to the controller I would also like to plot that data in an animation using `matplotlib`. The following matplotlib [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html) animation program can be run on any desktop.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

However, when inside of a remote connection, the animation is not displayed (i.e. the animation does not display when running on the Pi).

#### Static plot can be displayed in flask webserver

The following code is a matplotlib [example](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/user_interfaces/web_application_server_sgskip.html) on how to display a plot in a webserver. When running the following scrip on the Pi I can see the plot from my desktop by going to `http://raspberrypi.local:5000`.

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO

from flask import Flask
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    # Generate the figure **without using pyplot**.
    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.subplots()
    ax.plot([1, 2])
    # Save it to a temporary buffer.
    buf = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format="png")
    # Embed the result in the html output.
    data = base64.b64encode(buf.getbuffer()).decode("ascii")
    return f"<img src='data:image/png;base64,{data}'/>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

#### Question

The goal is to plot an animation from a Raspberry Pi and view the animation remotely. Is there any way to combine these two actions?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I know it is late but for those who facing this question later. I post my solution here.

1. First edit the pi sshd_config to on its X11 Forwarding by following:

> X11Forwarding yes
> 2. I used Windows laptop when making follow config. I think MacOS is the same.

> In my PowerShell profile, I add the following sentence by typing "code $PROFILE" in the shell :
> **$env:DISPLAY= 'localhost:0.0'**

3. Save above file and reopen powershell. Using **ssh -Y pi@yourip** to connect the pi and type > **echo $DISPLAY** in pi shell to confirm whether the setting works. For example:

> localhost:11.0

Then you can run your code and you will see a popup plot window~